# File Size not showing accurate in os.stat(y).st_size

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the filename and its sizes. code is running fine but the sizes coming up are off by kbs. For example a 3KB file is showing up as 2699 Byte.

```
created = []
fname = []

def list_files_and_sizes(*argv):
    path, sizes = argv
    size = []
    dirs=os.listdir(path)

    for i in dirs:
        fname.append(os.path.join(path, str(i)))

    for y in fname:
        file_stats = os.stat(y).st_size 

        if file_stats >= sizes:
            print(y, file_stats)
```

Comment: How do you know its 3KB?

Comment: Because I have seen the size in the windows file size.

Comment: I checked again and saw that windows does not show the exact size unless you take the cursor to the file. Hence the program is working as expected.